# ArrayList, checking size on 2 threads

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, copyonwritearraylist

I have a list:

ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();

On first thread I add elements (it is fast - 30/second)
On the second thread I read its size and print to file.

**First thread:**

```
synchronized(list){
    list.add(PlayerPosition);
}
```

**Second thread:**

```
synchronized(list){
if(list.size()>0)
    out.print(list.size() + " ");
}
```

It is the output of the file, only a part:
1 1 1 3 3 5 4 6 7 7 9 11 8 9 12 10 14 16

It is wrong, cause it should only increase. There can be 1 1 1, but can't be 11 8.

My program is big, BUT these are only occurences of this list (I have removed half of the code to debug it). There are no `list.remove()` etc. in the whole app.

I have a question: is this possible, that it acts like this?
Cause otherwise - it is my fault somewhere in the code.

And yeah, I have tried with CopyOnWriteArrayList - same thing.
Thanks!

Comment: May be It is just `out.print` problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the `print`s are not being executed in the order you expect.  Change the code of the second thread to the following:

```
synchronized(list){
    if (list.size() > 0) {
        synchronized (out) {
            out.print(list.size() + " ");
            out.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Your `OutputStream` is writing out characters to the terminal (or a file, or something else).  Without synchronizing on `out` and flushing, when Thread 2 tells the `OutputStream` to print, it's possible that the previous print has not finished yet.  Synchronizing and flushing forces Thread 2 to wait until all the characters have actually been written to the terminal before continuing.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve the code above a couple of ways.  First, you shouldn't have to implement the synchronization primitives yourself.  Java already has SynchronizedList built in.  See `Collections.synchronizedList(list)`.  This should all you to remove the list bases synchronize blocks.

For printing, the other answer is right, the is no guarantee that the file writes across threads will occur sequentially.  For example, thread 1 might write `8` to the print stream, then thread 2 writes `11`.  If thread 2 flushes then thread 1 flushes, the resultant file will contains `11`...`8`.  In that order (with possible other values inserted between them dependent on what else is flushed).